# Consume a rest service?

Tags: node.js

Is there a module that will abstract consuming a web service away from me.

So I can make a synchronous call: `var myObj = rest.getObjectFromUrl('url')` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a RESTful/HTTP-based webservice? If so  http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Otherwise maybe https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap for a SOAP webservice.

Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such module, but it's really extremely simple to do this:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'www.example.com',
  path: '/some/path/on/the/sever/?with=parameteers'
};

responseCallback= function(res) {
  var responseString = '';

  res
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
      responseString += chunk;
    });
    .on('end', function () {
      //do soemthing with the responseString
    });
}

http.request(options, responseCallback).end();
```